# Creating a range in Scala recursively

Tags: scala, recursion

I am new to Scala and I am still trying to get used to its syntax and rules.

I have a method that takes two inputs and returns a list with the numbers in between, excluding the last number. For example:

```
int a = 2
int b = 5
```

The list would be {2,3,4}

I have a method that creates a list but also account for the last digit.

```
def fromTo(low:Int,high:Int): List[Int] = {
    if(low == high)
      lo::Nil
    else
      lo::fromTo(low+1,hi)
    }
```

I tried creating a new variable but that did not work. Any ideas on how to make that last digit not be part of the list?

Comment: Consider your end condition. (Hint: it's **not** `low == high`)

Comment: Also, just in case, you can simply use `low until high toList`. And if you are OK with a general sequence instead of `List` you don't even need to call `toList`, and it will also use less memory.

Comment: Is this from a homework assignment? If not I don't see why you don't just do this `def fromTo(low:Int,high:Int): List[Int] = (low until high).toList`

Answer (score 1):

Think about your base case. What happens if you call `fromTo(a,a)` for some integer `a`.

Maybe a bit off topic, but you're also assuming that `low <= high` might want to look into that as well.

Comment: the low<= high is assumed because that's specified. I don't quite follow the base case comment. How is does that relate to the last digit not being part of the list

Comment: `from(a,a) = a :: Nil = List(a)` hence `from(a-1, a) = a - 1 :: from(a, a) = a-1 :: a :: Nil = List(a-1, a)`. Does this help at all?

Comment: Yes it does. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are specifically trying to do this with a recursive call but if all you really want is the list of numbers from X to Y excluding Y, you can just do the following:

```
scala> (2 until 5).toList
res3: List[Int] = List(2, 3, 4)
```